# No one is able to log into SharePoint sites after AD Migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, active-directory

We recently migrated AD to a new server. As a result, we lost access to SharePoint sites. We can still log into the Central Admin but no user (including the farm account and site collection admins) is able to access the sites. We get "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.".

What we've tried:

- Tried to migrate the users using `stsadm -o migrateuser` or SharePoint PowerShell.

We also cannot recreate any service application. The plan was to delete and recreate User Profile Service but we are unable to create a service application. An error "value cannot be null. parameter name: processaccount" is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check is there any errors in ULS logs and is there any *Audit Failures* at *Security* Event log on Web Server?
Make sure that your *SecurityTokenServiceApplication* and *SharePoint Hosted Services* pools are running in IIS.
Also make sure that this service issuing tokens:

```
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$webServiceCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceCollection($farm)
foreach ($service in $webServiceCollection)
{
    foreach ($webApp in $service.WebApplications)
    {
        $firstWebApp = $webApp
        $context = $firstWebApp.GetResponseUri([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone]::Default)
        Write-Host "Web Application Context:" $context.AbsoluteUri
        $token = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext]::SecurityTokenForContext($context)
        Write-Host "Token:" $token.InternalTokenReference
    }
}
```

Check that your superuser\reader accounts are present and valid, and try configure it from scratch.